# consulta sql no obtiene registros 0 usando left join

Tags: sql

Tengo dos tablas en mi base de datos.

Tabla 1 - public_usu

| id | correo | telefono | pais |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | usuario@gmail.com | 987654321 | mexico |
| 2 | usuario2@gmail.com | 987654322 | mexico |

y por otro lado otra tabla - reg_pagos

| id_pago | id_usu | fecha_r |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 1 | 2019-10-19 13:26:51 |
| 000002 | 1 | 2019-10-32 09:26:53 |

Si tengo estas tablas y estos registro e intento realizar

```
SELECT p.id, p.correo, p.telefono, p.pais, count(r.id_usu) as npagos FROM public_usu p  LEFT JOIN reg_pagos r on p.id=r.id_usu GROUP BY r.id_usu ORDER BY npagos ASC ;
```

obtengo algo como esto

| id | correo | telefono | pais | npagos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | usuario@gmail.com | 987654321 | mexico | 2 |

Aquí el problema, no me está regresando los usuarios que no tienen ningún pago registrado

Comment: Prueba cambiar la tabla en el group by. Agrupa por la tabla de usuarios (p.id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes el `group by` asi:

```
GROUP BY r.id_usu
```

Cambialo así:

```
GROUP BY p.id
```